# Having trouble adding PrimeFaces as EAR's library

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, jboss

I'd like to use PrimeFaces in my Java EE 6 (Jboss AS 7.1.1Final) application with this structure:

```
EAR
|- lib/
|    |- primefaces-4.0.jar
|
|- ejb-module.jar
|- webbapp1.war
|- webapp2.war
```

However, when deploying to JBoss AS 7, I'm getting several exceptions such as:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/primefaces/context/PrimeFacesContextFactory
```

(Please see the full stack trace [here on PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/Jdi1QkbB))

For EAR's pom.xml, I'm using this Maven dependency for PrimeFaces:

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

However, when I put the dependency into pom.xml of one WAR, it works, but I want to share the primefaces library between multiple WARs.

I've googled a lot but have not found any solution. Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot. Webapp libraries do not belong in `EAR/lib`, but in `WAR/WEB-INF/lib`. The `EAR/lib` is never intented as a "shared library" for all WAR projects of the EAR. It's that only for all EJB projects (the business services) of the EAR.

The `LinkageError` on a PrimeFaces-specific class which you're facing is caused because the (default) webapp-specific libraries like JSF API/impl are not available to the classloader as used by `EAR/lib`. This causes all libraries in the `EAR/lib` which have a (virtual) dependency in `WAR/WEB-INF/lib` to fail with class loading errors like `LinkageError`.

If you really really need a "shared library" for all WAR projects, then your best bet is putting the library in Java EE container itself (like as by default already done for JSF API/impl libraries). In case of JBoss, that's called a "module". I however wouldn't recommend that as that makes the webapp unportable across containers without specifically configuring the container by the serveradmin. Just give each webapp its own set of webapp libraries.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer, this is what I was afraid of. I just wanted to avoid having two same copies of the one library in my EAR to decrease the total archive size. Thanks for the clarification.