# Use Tomahawk on Mojarra in JBoss EAP 6.2

Tags: jsf, mojarra, tomahawk, jboss-eap-6

Is it possible, to use Apache Tomahawk on the JSF RI which ships which JBoss EAP 6.2?

I have an EAR-Deployment (skinny WARs) with an included webapp as WAR. I declared a Dependency in the Manifest of the WAR, to tell the classloader that Tomahawk needs the javax.faces.api

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Dependencies: javax.faces.api
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_35
```

I also checked, that no JAR is included in the EAR which is already shipped by JBoss like the JSF-API, Impl or any Jstl JARs.

I always end up with the following Exception: http://pastebin.com/QRN3Dwim

My web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Does anybody know, what is wrong? Or is is not possible to use Tomahawk on the JSF RI in JBoss EAP 6.2?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it now. Thanks to BalusC answer in: [Having trouble adding PrimeFaces as EAR's library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766234/having-trouble-adding-primefaces-as-ears-library/19767592#19767592) I realized that in a strict EE conform Application Server like JBoss EAP 6, webapp libraries are not allowed to reside in ear/lib.

After I placed tomahawk into WEB-INF/lib everything works fine.